# How to use the "Options" from the Darksky API to change the temperature from fahrenheit to celsius?

Tags: node.js, weather-api

I have looked into the forecast io (Darksky) api document, and find there are options that can change the temperature to celsius. I'm not sure how to use the code they provided.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the si units options to your parameters in the request. This should give you back temperature in celsius. For example:

```
const https = require('https');
var body = "";

const url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/your-key-goes-here/53.34929607,-6.26036167?units=si"

var req = https.request(url, (res) => {
      res.on('data', (d) => {
      body += d;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(data.currently.temperature);
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.end();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sir Awesome work like a charm, i found another wayt is to do something like this :`  var temperature = ((response.data.currently.temperature -32) * 5/9).toFixed(1);`

Comment: No problem, please mark my answer as correct, if you think this will be of help to others.

Answer (score 2):

for dark sky API :

https://api.darksky.net/forecast/5dc71e8b06915dee1cac240d5805eb66/24.68,83.06?units=si&exclude=hourly,flags,offset

For Retrofit :

//https://api.darksky.net/forecast/5dc71e8b06915dee1cac240d5805eb66/24.68,83.06?units=si

```
@GET("/forecast/{apikey}/{latitude},{longitude}?")
Call <SkyWeatherAPI> getWeatherDarkSky(@Path("apikey") String apikey, @Path("latitude") String latitude,
                                       @Path("longitude") String longitude, @Query("units") String units);
```

Call apiWeatherCall = mApiWeather.getWeatherDarkSky(API_KEY, "24.68","83.06", "si");